# Handling exceptions in a Swing UI (low level to high level and exception wrapping)

Tags: java, swing, exception

I wish to handle Exceptions in a meaningful way in a Swing application.

The following is inside an `actionPerformed` method. The `UiUtils#showError` displays a JOptionPane with a button that shows/hides the stack trace. ApplicationException is a custom class to translate low level Exceptions to something a user would understand.

One issue is that I'm not sure how to handle a `NullPointerException` that propagates up if a user doesn't select a file in the `JFileChooser` before this code. The `exportData` method purposefully checks for null on entry so no file handling is done.

Also, it seems that it would be a good approach to wrap a low level `Exception` (from the data layer for example). I'd like to modify `ApplicationException` to keep an instance instead of doing this in the `showError` method.

Finally, there's one thing that's bothering me and that's the possibility that a few Exceptions could happen simultaneously. I have no idea how to handle this so I'm open to any suggestions.

```
try {
    dataService.exportData(list, selectedFile);
} catch (IOException e) {
    UiUtils.showError(new ApplicationException("Input/Ouput error"), e );
} finally {

    if( list == null){
        UiUtils.showError(new ApplicationException("No data to export"), null );
    }

    if( selectedFile == null ){
        UiUtils.showError(new ApplicationException("No file selected"), null );
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To catch NullPointerException (or any RuntimeException for that matter) as well as your IOExceptionjust catch the most general exception type:

```
try {
   dataService.exportData(list, selectedFile);
} catch (Exception e) {
   UiUtils.showError(new ApplicationException(e), e );
} finally {
  ...
}
```

You can wrap the original exception into your ApplicationException by adding it as a "cause" parameter to the constructor, e.g.:

```
public class ApplicationException extends RuntimeException {

   public ApplicationException(Exception cause) {
       super(cause);
   }

   ...
}
```

Then the original exception would be always available via the getCause() method.

If you program is not multithreaded, I wouldn't worry about simultaneous exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, nothing happens "simultaneously" on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html); the [`EventQueue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html) enforces this. Moreover, Swing restarts the [EDT](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) on uncaught exceptions, but you can substitute your own handler, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448523/how-can-i-catch-event-dispatch-thread-edt-exceptions).

Addendum: @Sasha O has helpfully addressed the question directly. Alternatively, if you can arrange never to call the method with a `null` file handle, you can `assert` that fact as a precondition. See [*Programming With Assertions*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html) for details.

> This leaves me wondering in what cases inputs should be checked before a method call or inside a method.

A lot depends on the design. Instead of dealing with "No file selected," disable affected controls until a valid file has been selected. Instead of dealing with "No data to export," filter files by type, size or content in the chooser dialog. You still have to deal with I/O faults, but that's inevitable, as they are external to your program.

Addendum: This raises the problem of helping the user understand why a control is disabled. Some applications use a status bar to show such information. A tooltip can help, as shown [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html), even on a disabled control.

You should *not* use assertions to check the parameters of a public method.

Comment: Sorry about the old link, but that's when assertions were introduced. Any newer suggestions?

Comment: Interesting bit of info there about the EDT. I've already added an `UncaughtExceptionHandler`. Assertions do seem to be a good idea in that it's needless to pass null arguments to a method. This leaves me wondering in what cases inputs should be checked before a method call or inside a method.

Comment: nothing changed in the realm of java asserts, afaik. Then and now, checking preconditions is exactly what they are _not_ for ;-)

Comment: @kleopatra: Thanks for commenting on this. As noted in the article, one should _not_ use assertions to check the parameters of a public method. The goal should be to not throw an exception at all.

Answer (score 1):

Users don't understand exceptions however nicely you coat or layer them ;-) Design every end-user targeted application in a way that there are none. And keep in mind that exceptions are for .. well .. exceptional state, nothing else.

F.i, empty selection is a perfectly valid state of a ui which allows to select something (and act on the selected item). If acting on empty-selection bubbles up as a NPE, the acting logic is incorrect - it must cope with any valid state. One option to cope might be to be disabled (as trashgod already suggested), another might be to show a warning label as long as there's nothing selected.

Comment: Good point: some applications use a status bar or tooltip to guide the user on why a control is disabled.