# Neo4j - Lucene - maven shade plugin - Works fine through the Netbeans but doesnt work as jar

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, neo4j, lucene

I created a maven java application to execute some neo4j queries. I have a class in which neo4j queries are executing and one more in which i made a gui with Swing so i can use a button to execute a query and show the results in a textArea. Everything works fine if i run the project in Netbeans but when i'm using maven shade plugin to create a fat jar of this project, something happens and the neo4j commands dont work. I think that the problem is at lucene jars(from apache folder and neo4j folder) so i used some code in the pom.xml file to fix it, with no luck. Maybe the problem is because of same class name conflict in the classpath.

myJFrame.java

```
package com.mycompany.neo4jqueries;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

/**
 *
 * @author Dar309
 */
public class myJFrame extends JPanel {

    private JComboBox firstComboBox;
    private JTextArea queryTextArea, resultTextArea, infoTextArea;
    private String[] comboBoxItems, queryList;
    private JButton executeButton;
    private Font monosSpacedFont = new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12);
    private JProgressBar progressBar;
    private Task myTask;
    private long miliBeforeExec = 0, miliAfterExec = 0, execTime = 0;

    public myJFrame() {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel();
        BorderLayout fpL = new BorderLayout();
        firstPanel.setLayout(fpL);

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel topPanel1 = new JPanel();
        topPanel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

        comboBoxItems = new String[]{"1",
            "The Top 10 Stack Overflow Users",
            "The Top 5 tags That Jon Skeet Used in Asking Questions"};

        queryList = new String[]{"match (n) \nreturn head(labels(n)) as label, count(*)",
            "match (u:User) \nwith u,size( (u)-[:POSTED]->()) as posts order by posts desc limit 10 \nreturn u.name, posts",
            "match (u:User)-[:POSTED]->()-[:HAS_TAG]->(t:Tag) \nwhere u.name = 'Jon Skeet' \nreturn t,count(*) as posts order by posts desc limit 5"};

        firstComboBox = new JComboBox(comboBoxItems);

        firstComboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);
        firstComboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                queryTextArea.setText(queryList[firstComboBox.getSelectedIndex()]);

            }
        });

        topPanel1.add(firstComboBox);

        JPanel topPanel2 = new JPanel();
        topPanel2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        queryTextArea = new JTextArea();
        queryTextArea.setText(queryList[0]);
        queryTextArea.setFont(monosSpacedFont);
        queryTextArea.setEditable(false);

        JScrollPane queryScrollPane = new JScrollPane(queryTextArea);
        queryScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 110));

        topPanel2.add(queryScrollPane);

        JPanel topPanel3 = new JPanel();
        topPanel3.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
        progressBar.setValue(0);
        progressBar.setString("No progress yet");
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);

        executeButton = new JButton("Execute");
        executeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                executeButton.setEnabled(false);
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
                firstComboBox.setEnabled(false);
                progressBar.setString("Loading...");
                setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));

                miliBeforeExec = System.currentTimeMillis();

                //Instances of javax.swing.SwingWorker are not reusuable, so
                //we create new instances as needed.
                myTask = new Task();
                myTask.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                        if ("progress" == evt.getPropertyName()) {
//                            int progress = (Integer) evt.getNewValue();
//                            progressBar.setValue(progress);
                        }
                    }
                });
                myTask.execute();
            }
        });

        topPanel3.add(progressBar);
        topPanel3.add(executeButton);

        topPanel.add(topPanel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        topPanel.add(topPanel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        topPanel.add(topPanel3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        firstPanel.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel resultPanel = new JPanel();
        resultPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        resultTextArea = new JTextArea();
        resultTextArea.setFont(monosSpacedFont);
        resultTextArea.setText("");
        resultTextArea.setEditable(false);

        JScrollPane centerScrollPane = new JScrollPane(resultTextArea);
        centerScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(550, 200));
        centerScrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 0, 10, 0));
        resultPanel.add(centerScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        infoTextArea = new JTextArea();
        infoTextArea.setRows(2);
        infoTextArea.setFont(monosSpacedFont);
        infoTextArea.setEditable(false);

        resultPanel.add(infoTextArea, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        firstPanel.add(resultPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        add(firstPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
//        frame.setSize(650, 550);
        frame.setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width / 2,Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height / 2);
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight()));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Execute your Neo4j queries");

        Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int x = (int) ((dimension.getWidth() - frame.getWidth()) / 2);
        int y = (int) ((dimension.getHeight() - frame.getHeight()) / 2);
        frame.setLocation(x, y);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        JComponent newContentPane = new myJFrame();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class Task extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

        /*
         * Main task. Executed in background thread.
         */
        @Override
        public Void doInBackground() {
//            Random random = new Random();
//            int progress = 0;
            //Initialize progress property.
            setProgress(0);

            System.out.println("popo");
            resultTextArea.append("popo");
            myQuery mq = new myQuery();
            mq.run(myJFrame.this);
            resultTextArea.append("metaaaa");
            System.out.println("metaaa");

//            setProgress(Math.min(progress, 100));
            return null;
        }

        /*
         * Executed in event dispatching thread
         */
        @Override
        public void done() {
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
            executeButton.setEnabled(true);
            firstComboBox.setEnabled(true);
//            resultTextArea.setCaretPosition(resultTextArea.getText().length());
            setCursor(null); //turn off the wait cursor

            miliAfterExec = System.currentTimeMillis();
            execTime = miliAfterExec - miliBeforeExec;
//            execTime += 11140000;

            if (execTime < 60 * 1000) {
                infoTextArea.setText("Total time: " + (double) (execTime / 1000.000) + "s");
            }          
//            else if(execTime >= (60 * 1000) && execTime < (3600 * 1000) ){
            else if (execTime >= (60 * 1000)) {
                long temp = execTime;
                for (long i = 0; i < execTime / (60 * 1000); i++) {
                    temp -= (60 * 1000);
                }
                infoTextArea.setText("Total time: " + (execTime / (60 * 1000)) + ":" + (double) (temp / 1000.000) + "s");
            }
            Date date = new Date();
            infoTextArea.append("\nFinished at: " + date.toString());

            progressBar.setString("Done!");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public JTextArea getResultTextArea() {
        return resultTextArea;
    }

    public JTextArea getQueryTextArea() {
        return queryTextArea;
    }

}
```

myQuery.java

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.mycompany.neo4jqueries;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Result;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
import org.neo4j.helpers.collection.Iterators;

/**
 *
 * @author Dar309
 */
public class myQuery {

    private static final File DB_PATH = new File("D:/IU/Διπλωματική/neo4j-community-3.1.2/data/databases/graph.db");
    String resultString;
    String columnsString;
    String nodeResult;
    String rows = "";


    void run(myJFrame myFrame) {
        GraphDatabaseService db = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);

        myFrame.getResultTextArea().append("sdadsdsadsads");
        System.out.println("naiiiii");
        try (Transaction ignored = db.beginTx();
//                Result result = db.execute("match (u:User) with u,size( (u)-[:POSTED]->()) as posts order by posts desc limit 10 return u.name, posts")) {
                Result result = db.execute(myFrame.getQueryTextArea().getText() ) ) {

            // START SNIPPET: columns
            List<String> columns = result.columns();
            // END SNIPPET: columns

            columnsString = columns.toString();
//            resultString = db.execute( "match (u:User) with u,size( (u)-[:POSTED]->()) as posts order by posts desc limit 10 return u.name, posts" ).resultAsString();
            resultString = result.resultAsString();
            System.out.println("\n\ncolumnsString\n------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(columnsString);

            System.out.println("\n\nresultString\n------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(resultString);
            myFrame.getResultTextArea().append(resultString);

            try {
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("the-file-name.txt", "UTF-8");
                writer.print(resultString);
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // do something
            }
        }

        db.shutdown();
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>Neo4jQueries</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <name>neo4jQueries</name>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <shadedClassifierName>shaded</shadedClassifierName>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                            <relocations>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>org.apache.lucene</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>shaded_lucene_5_5_0.org.apache.lucene</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>org.neo4j</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>shaded_neo4j.org.neo4j</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                            </relocations>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.mycompany.neo4jqueries.myJFrame</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>neo4j-repo</id>
            <name>Neo4j Repository</name>
            <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

When i double click on jar, i see the gui and all works fine till myQuery class is called, then no neo4j commands are executing but no error message showed.

Does anyone can help me solve this please?

Answer (score 0):

Your program hardcodes the path to the neo4j DB.

So, if you are not running the jar file on the same machine on which you developed your code, it would not be able to find the DB and will throw an exception.

However, as the doc for [InvokeLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)) says, if the `Runnable` you pass to it:

> throws an uncaught exception the event dispatching thread will unwind
>   (not the current thread)

That means that your thread will never see any uncaught exceptions unless you explicitly tell Swing to use an exception handler that you provide. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95767/how-can-i-catch-awt-thread-exceptions-in-java) and its 2 top-scoring answers for how to do that (depending on which version of Java you are using).

Comment: I didnt get your answer, i will search it a little though. Btw i solved the problem. I just install Eclipse and didnt use Netbeans anymore. In Eclipse there is an option to export your project to a file, so i chose to export my project to executable jar file with all included packages packed in the new jar.(its the second choice of the three choices in executable jar option) So now i have an executable jar and all work fine because the problem was the same class name conflict.